# CaseHistory records are not accessible via Constructor?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, custom-controller

I have a VF page which has a Custom Controller class. In that, I have this code in the Constructor for querying required data:

```
public final Case currentCase;
public final List<CaseHistory> caseHis;

/* Inside Constructor(Partial code provided here) */
String pageCaseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');

currentCase = [Select  Id,Contact.MailingStreet,
                       Contact.MailingCity,
                       Contact.MailingState From Case Where Id = :pageCaseId];

List<CaseHistory> caseHis = [Select OldValue, NewValue, Field, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name
                                         From CaseHistory Where CaseId =:currentCase.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];


/* Get methods */
// Case record
public Case getCase(){
    return curCase;
}

//CaseHistory records
public List<CaseHistory> getCaseHistory(){
    return caseHis;
}
```

In the VF page, I can able to display all the Case field, but not the CaseHistory. Here is the part of code I am trying to display CaseHistory records:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!caseHistory}" var="casHistory">
                    <div class="col1">
                        <p>{!casHistory.OldValue}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col2" >
                        <p>{!casHistory.NewValue}</p>
                    </div>
 </apex:repeat>
```

I am not getting any values displayed for CaseHistory. Am I doing anything wrong at any part of the code?

Comment: I assume history tracking is enabled. Are you able to get records from developer console with same profile.

Comment: Yes, I can see the CaseHistory records in the Constructor(using System.debug), but when I do the same in the CaseHistory Get method, I am getting null.

Comment: Oh great. I realized what I have done wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you used a Local variable and showing different variable with the same name on the page.

```
public final Case currentCase;
public List<CaseHistory> caseHis {public get;private set;}

/* Inside Constructor(Partial code provided here) */
String pageCaseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');

currentCase = [Select  Id,Contact.MailingStreet,
                       Contact.MailingCity,
                       Contact.MailingState From Case Where Id = :pageCaseId];

 caseHis = [Select OldValue, NewValue, Field, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name
                                         From CaseHistory Where CaseId =:currentCase.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
```

Page variable name not correct

```
<apex:repeat value="{!caseHis}" var="casHistory">
                    <div class="col1">
                        <p>{!casHistory.OldValue}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col2" >
                        <p>{!casHistory.NewValue}</p>
                    </div>
 </apex:repeat>
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: My understanding: **You have changed the caseHis declaration**, correct? 
If yes, that didn't worked. Even I tried using `{ get; set; }` which didn't work either.

Comment: The variable name also not correct on the page and you declared a local variable which is not required. The above code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Main issue is in this line at Constructor:

```
List<CaseHistory> caseHis = [Select OldValue, NewValue, Field, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name
                                         From CaseHistory Where CaseId =:currentCase.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
```

Since you are using class level variable `caseHis` which is returned by `getCaseHistory()` method.

This class level variable is null as you have declared the same variable in the constructor as above.

So, remove local variable of same name in the Constructor.

It should be in the Constructor:

```
caseHis = [Select OldValue, NewValue, Field, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name
                                         From CaseHistory Where CaseId =:currentCase.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
```